# Odd results with parsing a Datetime c#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have the following code:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES", true);
date = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", culture);
```

for _date = "2012-11-17 15:00"

it throws an exception

but for _date = "2012-11-17 10:00" works

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `HH` instead of `hh`

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", culture);
```

`HH` is for *24-hr*
`hh` is for *12-hr*

Comment: yes you are right, just found it too... well at least posting the question helped me to find the error, thanks for the quick answer as well.